# Java Atomic-переменные такие уж атомарные?

Tags: java, concurrency

Как известно, существует ряд Atomic-оболочек для примитивов. Главный принцип - они не использую привычную синхронизацию (synchronized), а реализуют "Compare and Set operation".

Например, возьмём AtomicLong. Чтобы увеличить текущее значение, есть метод *getAndAdd*.

Заглянем в сорцы:

```
private volatile long value;

public final long get() {
    return value;
}

public final long getAndAdd(long delta) {
    while (true) {
        long current = get();
        long next = current + delta;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: где тут атомарность операции? Что мешает другому потоку зайти внутрь while или вообще, поменяв значение value, передать в next совсем не то, чтобы просечено в current?

Тем более, что *value* объявлено как volatile, что говорит о том, что это значение общее для всех потенциальных потоков.

Comment: Вы бы уж тогда и метод compareAndSet добавили сюда.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что первым параметром `compareAndSet` передается текущее значение `value`.  Если другой поток зайдет и успеет провести свой инкремент, то `compareAndSet` просто вернет `false` и цикл повторится. А сама операция CAS атомарна.

На всякий случай напомню: локальные переменные у каждого потока, конечно, будут свои.

Comment: > Тем более, что value объявлено как volatile

Само собой, читать то его все хотят.

Comment: > Вы бы уж тогда и метод compareAndSet добавили сюда.

@huffman, это нативный метод.

Comment: @Nofate строго говоря, это не так :)

    public final boolean compareAndSet(long expect, long update) {
        return unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
    }

Вот swap уже нативный.

Comment: @a_gura, само собой )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Что мешает другому потоку зайти внутрь while или вообще, поменяв значение value, передать в next совсем не то, чтобы просечено в current?
```

Вы недопонимаете суть работы конкурирующих потоков. То, что другие потоки могут войти в цикл `while` - не страшно. Переменные `current` и `next` - локальные, а следовательно у каждого потока свои экземпляры этих переменных.

Проблема лишь в разделяемом состоянии, т.е. переменной `value`. Т.к. переменная `value` объявлена с модификатором `volatile`, то гарантируется выполнение отношениея happens-before, что ведет к тому, что измененное значение этой переменной увидят все потоки.

Метод `compareAndSet` представляет из себя механизм оптимистичной блокировки и позволяет изменить значение `value`, только если оно равно ожидаемому значению (т.е. `current`).

Если же значение `value` было изменено в другом потоке, то оно не будет равно ожидаемому значению. Следовательно метод `compareAndSet` вернет значение `false`, что приведет к новой итерации цикла `while` в методе `getAndAdd`. Т.е. новое значение `value` будет перезачитано в переменную `current`, после чего будет произведено сложение и новая попытка записи получившегося значения (т.е. `next`).

Comment: да, действительно.. совершенно забыл о локальных переменных. спасибо! :)